# JavaScript function that outputs heading element

Tags: javascript, forms, html-heading

Hi I'm a beginner and was looking to get some help on this. How can I make it so that addHeading( ) gets the heading type from the drop down box and text from the form, and creates/outputs a corresponding heading element? As of now its only outputting the text and not the actual heading with the corresponding size. Here's what I have so far. I wasn't able to find a specific example or anything on this. Thanks in advance.

```js
function addHeading() {
    var x = document.getElementById("heading");
    var headingText =
        document.getElementById("headingText").value;

    document.getElementById("divHeading").innerHTML = headingText;
}

function clearHeading() {
    document.getElementById('divHeading').innerHTML = headingText = [];
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid khaki;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
form h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
input {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form id='headingForm'>
  <h2>Heading Form</h2>
  <span>Heading Type:</span>
  <select id='heading' name='heading'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
   </select>
  <br>
  <span>Text:</span>
  <input required='required' type='text' name='headingText' 
id='headingText'>
  <br>
  <input type='button' value='Add Heading' onclick='addHeading()'>
  <input type='button' value='Clear Heading' onclick='clearHeading()'>
  <div id='divHeading'></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamically create element using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590414/dynamically-create-element-using-javascript)

Comment: This is an example to [create H1 element](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-would-you-create-a-new-h1-element-with-javascript-document-submit-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1er11jbm/):

```js
function addHeading(){
    var x = document.getElementById("heading").value;
    var headingText = document.getElementById("headingText").value;
    document.getElementById("divHeading").innerHTML = '<h'+x+'>'+headingText+'</h'+x+'>';
}

function clearHeading() {
    document.getElementById('divHeading').innerHTML = '';
    //document.querySelector('#headingText').value = '';
}
```

```css
form {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid khaki;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
form h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
input {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form id='headingForm'>
    <h2>Heading Form</h2>
    <span>Heading Type:</span>
    <select id='heading' name='heading'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <span>Text:</span>
    <input required='required' type='text' name='headingText' id='headingText'>
    <br>
    <input type='button' value='Add Heading' onclick='addHeading()'>
    <input type='button' value='Clear Heading' onclick='clearHeading()'>
    <div id='divHeading'></div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad it helps! :)